# Critical Points in Higher Dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $$f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ be a twice continuously differentiable function. Show that if (0,0) is a non-degenerate critical point for f, and $$\forall m \in \mathbb{R},f(x,mx)$$ has a local minimum at (0,0), then $$f$$ has a local minimum at the origin.

Comment: Do you mean that $g(x) = f(x, mx) $ has a local minimum at $x=0$ in your second sentence? All you have written is that  $g(x) = f(x, mx)$ has a local minimum in which case $(0,0)$ is not necessarily a local minimum of $f$

Comment: So what have you tried, and where are you running into trouble?

Comment: @VishnuMangalath...Edited it!

Comment: @PaulSinclair. So I'm basically arguing by contradiction. As (0,0) is a non-degenerate critical point, the determinant of the Hessian Matrix is non-zero. If the determinant is positive, but the Hessian Matrix is negative definite, then f has a local maximum at (0,0), and hence so does f(x,mx). If the determinant is negative, then f has a saddle point at (0,0)...

Comment: @PaulSinclair...If f has a saddle point at (0,0), then in any epsilon neighbourhood of (0,0), there exists a point (a,b) s.t. f(a,b)<f(0,0). As f is cts, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists a delta neighbour around (a,b) s.t. for every point (e,f) in B((a,b),r), f(e,f)<f(0,0). I can then pick a non-zero e and an f which satisfies this. If I now define x=e and m=f/e, it then follows that f(x,mx)=f(e,f)<f(0,0). I'm not sure however if my m can depend on e and f, as these are indirectly dependent on epsilon.

Comment: @MohidMuhammad - that needs to be explained in your post, not in the comments.